# Proper way to deploy Meteor app without data to custom server

Tags: meteor, deployment

I want to deploy a meteor app to some custom Linux server. Sure currently installed project packages must be preserved on the destination server.

So I need to pack my local project structure, upload it to the server and unpack it there (or something else).

I think I need (or can) at least remove `.meteor/local/*` folder content.

What about `.meteor/.id` file content? Anything else?

I can't find any documentation explaining how to do this but taking into account Meteor's usage simplicity philosophy there must be some simple command to pack application distro.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying you should use the `meteor build`[(docs)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteorbuild) command which creates a tarball contains your application.

But to make the setup even simpler you could use [Meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) takes care of the whole deployment process even including preparation of the target server.

Comment: Hello, In case I have a tarball built with `meteor build` command, what my further steps to deploy it? It contains different structure than my dev server.